# Happstack dependency failure on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: haskell, happstack

I am trying to install Happstack using the following command:

> cabal install happstack

### Specifications:

1. Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)
2. GHC 7.8.3
3. cabal 1.20.0.2

### Error Messages:

> ld: library not found for -lHSstm-2.4.3-ghc7.8.3
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Failed to install threads-0.5.1.2
>
> cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>
> happstack-7.0.2 depends on threads-0.5.1.2 which failed to install.
>
> happstack-server-7.3.9 depends on threads-0.5.1.2 which failed to install.
>
> system-filepath-0.4.12 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>
> ExitFailure 1
>
> threads-0.5.1.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>
> ExitFailure 1

Comment: How did you install GHC? I don't have a Mac myself, but I've heard scary things about Homebrew.

Comment: This error message doesn't say much, you should run the same command with `-v3`.

Comment: Its okay. I got rid of everything and just installed using the Haskell Platform package distributed by GHC. Installing ghc via homebrew seemed to have provide a non-stable version of ghc, thus making the cabal libraries incompatible.